Create all Combination from a vector with repeating elements - R
I would like to know if there is a simple solution to finding all combination of a vector with repeating elements. The practical application is in combinatorics math. For example:
There is an urn with 2 red and 2 black balls in how many different ways can all 4 balls be drawn.
The only solution I was able to find is below but I am sure there must be a simpler code to generate this? Thank you for your help.
combin <- permutations(n = 4, r = 4, v = 1:4)
# mapping 
#1 -> 1 : Red
# 2-> 1 : Red
# 3-> 0 : Black
#4 -> 0 : Black

combin<-replace(combin, combin == 2, 1)
combin <- replace(combin, combin == 3, 0)
combin <- replace(combin, combin == 4, 0)
combin <- unique(combin)
combin

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    1    0    1
[6,]    0    0    1    1


Define the urn and mention the packages this example is going to use.
# library(combinat)
# library(gtools)
# library(RcppAlgos)

urn <- c("red", "red", "black", "black")

Created on 2024-09-08 with reprex v2.1.0
First the permutations with package combinat.
urn <- c("red", "red", "black", "black")

combinat::permn(urn) |> do.call(rbind, args = _) |> unique()
#>      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
#> [1,] "red"   "red"   "black" "black"
#> [2,] "red"   "black" "red"   "black"
#> [3,] "black" "red"   "red"   "black"
#> [4,] "black" "red"   "black" "red"  
#> [5,] "red"   "black" "black" "red"  
#> [6,] "black" "black" "red"   "red"

Created on 2024-09-08 with reprex v2.1.0
Now with package gtools. This is more complicated because function gtools::permutations only permutes vectors with all elements different.
i <- gtools::permutations(4, 4, seq_along(urn))
apply(i, 1L, \(j) urn[j]) |> t() |> unique()
#>      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
#> [1,] "red"   "red"   "black" "black"
#> [2,] "red"   "black" "red"   "black"
#> [3,] "red"   "black" "black" "red"  
#> [4,] "black" "red"   "red"   "black"
#> [5,] "black" "red"   "black" "red"  
#> [6,] "black" "black" "red"   "red"

urn |>
  seq_along() |>
  gtools::permutations(4, 4, v = _) |>
  apply(1L, \(i) urn[i]) |>
  t() |>
  unique()
#>      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
#> [1,] "red"   "red"   "black" "black"
#> [2,] "red"   "black" "red"   "black"
#> [3,] "red"   "black" "black" "red"  
#> [4,] "black" "red"   "red"   "black"
#> [5,] "black" "red"   "black" "red"  
#> [6,] "black" "black" "red"   "red"

Created on 2024-09-08 with reprex v2.1.0
Finally, with the performant package RcppAlgos.
RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(urn, 4L) |> unique()
#>      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
#> [1,] "red"   "red"   "black" "black"
#> [2,] "red"   "black" "red"   "black"
#> [3,] "red"   "black" "black" "red"  
#> [4,] "black" "red"   "red"   "black"
#> [5,] "black" "red"   "black" "red"  
#> [6,] "black" "black" "red"   "red"

Created on 2024-09-08 with reprex v2.1.0

If you want the output as a binary matrix, use any of the above, compare to "red" and coerce the result to integer.
urn <- c("red", "red", "black", "black")
RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(urn, 4L) |> unique() -> res
+(res == "red")
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    1    0    0
#> [2,]    1    0    1    0
#> [3,]    1    0    0    1
#> [4,]    0    1    1    0
#> [5,]    0    1    0    1
#> [6,]    0    0    1    1

Created on 2024-09-08 with reprex v2.1.0

You can try permuteGeneral with freqs for multiset cases
> library(RcppAlgos)

> permuteGeneral(c("red", "black"), 4, freqs = rep(2, 2))
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]
[1,] "red"   "red"   "black" "black"
[2,] "red"   "black" "red"   "black"
[3,] "red"   "black" "black" "red"
[4,] "black" "red"   "red"   "black"
[5,] "black" "red"   "black" "red"
[6,] "black" "black" "red"   "red"

